# Add permissions for a user to folders and files

Tags: debian, chown

I have a user `jenkins` that creates files and folders in (on ubuntu) :

```
/var/jenkins/workspace/my-project
```

e.g:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Mar 21 16:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 jenkins jenkins   4096 Mar 21 16:42 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 545865 Mar 21 16:41 config/
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 545147 Mar 21 16:40 1.zip
```

Now I need my `tomcat6` user to read files from the `config` folder. If I manually do:

```
sudo chown -R tomcat6:tomcat6 config
```

Before starting tomcat it works. But how do I permanently give tomcat permissions to read and even write to the config folder?

As suggested I am now trying to put the `tomcat6` user in the `jenkins` group  using `vigr`:
http://linux.die.net/man/8/vigr

running `vigr -g` give me (just a snippet):

```
messagebus:x:106:
jenkins:x:1001:
puppet:x:107:
tomcat6:x:108:
```

But am not sure how I add then tomcat6 user to the jenkins group

Comment: If the files are now own by tomcat itself what is the problem ? 
youprobably find the best way to give tomcat the right to read the files

Comment: How to I give tomcat6 user rights to read the files/folders own by jenkins user?

Comment: `sudo chown -R tomcat6:tomcat6 config` does that work ?

Comment: Jep as I described that works fine. But that folder is deleted and created each time I run my job and then jenkins owns it again.

Comment: here is what should look like your /etc/group:
messagebus:x:106:
**jenkins:x:1001:tomcat6**
puppet:x:107:
tomcat6:x:108:

Answer (score 2):

hy,

the easiest way (and probably the worst) is to put the user tomcat6 in the jenkins group.
as all users in jenkins have permission to read in your description:
drwx***r-x***r-x  2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Mar 21 14:30 config/

to achieve that, look at vigr which is a vi wrapper to edit /etc/group file

hope this helps,

Comment: If for some reason that is not doable, do `man setfacl`.

Comment: if directory is deleted then recreated automatically, posix acls won't last.
beside posix acls are a bit trickier to use i think in his case :)

Comment: An ACL on the parent directory will be inherited, though.